# Customize the primary key data type for Identity in asp.net core 2 creates problems in UserStore

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I need the primary key for my user class in Identity to be long instead of the default string. Following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-primary-key-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore2x) MS tutorial. So i do all that (just replace GUID in the tutorial with long) and everything was looking good until I was working on created a seed class

```
var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
```

gives me the squiggles on ApplicationUser with the message:

Error   CS0311  The type 'WSCPA_AC.Models.ApplicationUser' cannot be used as type parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method 'UserStore'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'WSCPA_AC.Models.ApplicationUser' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser'.

Now I see mention of this sort of problem in the comments at the bottom of the tutorial. Do I have to somehow override the UserStore class, and if so, how?

Comment: Why are you using UserStore directly to seed? Inject UserManager instead.

Comment: @Chris Pratt I was following some examples of seeding in Core 2, but trying it your way at least builds!

Comment: UserStore is mostly a low-level abstraction. It's *very* rare to see it used directly outside of UserManager.

Comment: It might have been an attempt to avoid the async-only nature of UserManager, but there's ways to run your seeding async.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will need to use the base class of `UserStore` which has a signature of `UserStore<TUser, TRole, TContext, TKey>` as follows:

```cs
var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<long>, TContext, long>(context);
```

Where `TContext` is the type of your database context.